# cmd lines tools component is missing althout I have already installed it

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, sdk

I am trying to intall flutter but when I run the command `flutter doctor` in the terminal I get the following screen.

[image]

**Things I have tried:**

- I have already tried to install the cmdline-tools from the android studio
- I have also configured the system PATH

Images of configuration:

**cmdline-tools installation**

[image]

**PATH configuration**

[image]

But still nothing works. Also if I try the command `sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"` it says that sdkmanager is not recognized. I suspect this might happening because I change the Android SDK Location in Android studio like below:

[image]

But I am not sure if this is the cause of the problem.